# How to understand plusignment operator in puppet

Tags: puppet

In URL https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/glossary.html#plusignment-operator, here is its explanation:

```
The +> operator, which allows you to add values to resource attributes using the (‘plusignment’) syntax. Useful when you want to override resource attributes without having to respecify already declared values.
```

For example, I have code like this:

```
Package {
    require => File['/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache'],
}
package { 'php5-cgi':
    ensure  => present,
}
Package[ 'php5-cli' ] {
    require +> Package['php5-cgi'],
}
```

What did the operator `+>` mean here?

Other sample:

```
subscribe +> Sshkey['www.example.com']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute in question takes a value that is composed of the right hand side and whatever it would have taken otherwise.

In your example, the `package { 'php5-cgi' }` would normally use a `require` value of `File['/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache']`, since it is the default for all `package` resources. Through the plusignment, you end up with a value of

```
require => [ File['/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache'], Package['php5-cgi'] ]
```

The `php5-cli` package builds a relation to both the referenced `file` and the `php5-cgi` package.

The same logic will apply to the `subscribe` metaparameter from your second example. I cannot comment on the whole semantics without more context.

The plusignment works for all resource attributes, although the resulting array values will not make sense for many of them.

Comment: Thanks, the original explanation `override resource attributes` makes me confused. Now I understand it is `append`, not `override`. Then `+` makes sense for me.